# save files to a non-persistent bootable drive

Tags: linux, usb, liveusb

good morning / good evening everyone.
being a neophyte the question below might seem a bit obvious but I hope it will be useful to others as well.
in an USB I installed a Linux live distro (Kali Linux) in a NON persistent way.
I would like to understand if I can add some bash files that I will need every time I use the machine without making it persistence.
I have already tried to create a directory but this is not displayed by the machine and I cannot find the "cdrom" folder that some forums have talked about.
The directory is located directly in the root path of the drive, it is not a subdirectory.
i can see files and folders from windows 10.

to do this would you need a new partition or could it be done in a simpler way?

I've seen many other forums before but can't find the answer.
thanks

(edit)
how can i put some file from windows to my USB and be able to use them into the OS of the USB (Linux) without making a persistent live USB?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Add another partition. Likely, you'd need to do that *before* making a bootable USB. And since you'd need to make a new one, why *not* make it persistent? Yes it's slow to write to the USB, but if you're *not* doing so, why worry?

Comment: I use the USB OS as a "lab", so I need it to reset every time.
the file I want to be able to share contains some commands like change the keyboard layout etc. and therefore I need it every time I open the machine.